# My work is slowing down other users on the same machine

Tags: memory, cpu

I am working on a university computer. I am trying to run a job which is apparently slowing other users down. I ran 'top' to see what was going on. I was running near 100% of the CPU, but I think there are 24 CPUs (I pressed '1' while I was in 'top')? But the MEM% that I was using was creeping up and up as the process continues. So I believe that that was RAM that I was using up? Is that the RAM for the machine as a whole? i.e. once I get near 100%, everything is going to stop working for people who are using the came machine? Or is the RAM just for the CPU I am using. If so, why does it slow down the work of other people.

I'm trying to ask a question without understanding the situation, so please point out what more information I need to provide.

Comment: What precisely is your question?  You have several believes and not enough hard facts, provide us hard facts, hard to help without those.

Comment: If it turns out that the problem is CPU cycles, you should look into the `nice` command.  You can probably even use a system call to let you r program `nice` itself.  see `man -S 2 nice`

Comment: As I said, I am trying to learn about these things, so it's difficult to know what information I need to provide. I basically want to know if the MEM% that I was increasingly using (according to top) is the reason I am slowing everyone else down.

Comment: The mem% figure is system wide, so if you are using a large portion, that would slow everyone else down as they would start swapping.